# SVG begin="id.end" attribute in animate tag not working

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, svg

Why am I doing wrong in the following code snnipet? Why is the rectangle not being animated in Chrome(v 39) and Firefox(v 33) after the circle ends its animation?

```html
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <svg width="500" height="350">
  <circle id="orange-circle" r="30" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange" />
  <rect id="blue-rectangle" width="50" height="50" x="25" y="200" fill="#0099cc"></rect>
  
  <animate 
           xlink:href="#orange-circle"
           attributeName="cx"
           from="50"
           to="450" 
           dur="5s"
           begin="click"
           fill="freeze" 
           id="circ-anim"/>
  
  <animate 
           xlink:href="#blue-rectangle"
           attributeName="x" 
           from="50"
           to="425" 
           dur="5s"
           begin="circ-anim.end"
           fill="freeze" 
           id="rect-anim"/>
  
</svg>
<p>Click on the circle to animate it, and animate the rectangle after it.</p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either change the id of the circle from circ-anim to say circ and fix up the begin reference or escape the - sign and it will work.

SMIL uses + and - to indicate offsets e.g. begin="circ.end - 1" would start 1 second before the end of the circ animation ends so you can't use + or - in ids that you want to animate.

You can escape the id in SMIL via

```
xlink:href="#orange\-circle"
```

if you really want to keep the sign character.

The SMIL specification [says this about parsing the begin attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/SMIL3/smil-timing.html#q21)...

> Build a token substring up to but not including any sign indicator (i.e. strip off any offset)...